# batch remove pdf password using Acrobat pro 11 or other software

Tags: pdf, batch, adobe-acrobat, decryption

I have thousands of pdf with password encrypted and i want to remove the password in batch process, i tried acrobat 11 pro and created a batch action to remove, but its til prompt me every to enter a password for every documents.

Any other software can remove the pdf in batch process?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use PDFTK to remove the password. I'm not sure what platform you are on but it will work on linux. Use shell scripts to batch script your process.

[Removing password from pdf on linux command line](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/)

EDIT:
Python can be used to decrypt AES encrypted PDF files.
Look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447600/decrypting-pdf-protected-by-aes-256bit-using-the-right-password)

Comment: using windows 7, there are no linux computer in my environment

Comment: It should work in [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). The pdftk package is there.

Comment: @hkinterview You could build a small VM using xubuntu on top of windows environment.

Comment: @BubuIIC it could work on cygwin but in my personal opinion VM would be faster and monolithic (easier cleanup).

Comment: I like using *nix tools during my tim ein windows. Cygwin integrates better into the normal windows environment. But ultimately it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Ok, so how to remove password on multiple files using PDFTK? The example only show remove password on single file

Comment: @hkinterview scripting, wildcards, loops.

Comment: just tested, there is input error using the pdftk

Comment: just googled pdftk seems too old to open the encrypted documents

Comment: pdftk doesn't support AES > encryption

Comment: @hkinterview I updated my post, you can use python to decrypt the AES encrypted PDFs.

Comment: i've downloaded Free PDF Unlocker already solved the problem.

Comment: @hkinterview cool, that means you would never return to this site as your question was never answered.

Comment: For future reference, [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) has a perfectly functional Windows command-line version available.

Comment: @Karan I believe so but Linux has better batch capabilities than windows in my personal opinion.

Comment: Yeah, just mentioned it due to all the talk of using it in a VM, via cygwin etc.